# Include files into war classes folder

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Is there a way how to include some files into war's classes folder?
Eclipse builds the war right, but my ant script cant include files to classes folder.

```
...
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
    <property name="classes.dir" location="${build.dir}/classes" />

    <target name="war" depends="mklib, retrieve, compile">
    <war destfile="${war.file}" webxml="${webContent.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <classes dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <fileset dir="${webContent.dir}" excludes="**/servlet-api*.jar,**/jsp-api*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.xml,**/*.sql" />
    </war>
</target>
...
```

Comment: Which ones you want to include?

Comment: xml and sql files, trying to include em on this row: <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.xml,**/*.sql" /> ... but it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to thank you, who took a little time to think about this solution.
Anyway all i needed was much simpler

```
<target name="war" depends="mklib, retrieve, compile">
    <war destfile="${war.file}" webxml="${webContent.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <classes dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <classes dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/start.xml, **/per*.xml, **/*.sql" />
        <fileset dir="${webContent.dir}" excludes="**/servlet-api*.jar,**/jsp-api*.jar" />
    </war>
</target>
```

All needed to do is write include or includes attribute to classes

Answer (score 1):

The `<classes/>` sub-entity can be used for stuff besides `*.class` files. All the `<classes/>` sub-entity does is put the files specified in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory of your war:

```
<target name="war" depends="mklib, retrieve, compile">
<war destfile="${war.file}" webxml="${webContent.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <classes dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <classes dir="${resources.dir}"/>  <!-- Other files that are in WEB-INF/classes -->
</war>
```

(I would have used your example, but you have `<fileset dir="${classes.dir}"` which means you're placing stuff in your `${classes.dir}` (where you compiled your code) into the root of your war which is probably not what you want.(

You can also use `<zipfileset/>` instead of plain `<fileset>`. The `<zipfileset>` takes all the same parameters and sub-entities as `<fileset>`, but also includes a `prefix` parameter where you can specify the prefix directory:

```
<target name="war" depends="mklib, retrieve, compile">
<war destfile="${war.file}" webxml="${webContent.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <classes dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <classes dir="${resources.dir}"/>
    <zipfileset prefix="foo/resources"
       dir="${foo.dir}">
       <include name="**/*.foo"/>
    </zipfileset>
</war>
```